# Restrict access to path vi IPTables

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, centos6.4

I want to restrict access to a path via iptables
- I try this one and its work on the whole site

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m string --algo bm --string 'example.com' -j DROP
```

but I want to restrict access to specific folder like "example.com/test", but It didn't catch any packets

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m string --algo bm --string 'example.com/test' -j DROP
```

Please any suggestion ?

Comment: iptables doesn't work like this.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong network layer.  While you probably *could* do some horrible hackjob to block that via IPTables on unencrypted http,  https is encrypted so IPTables dont even see full URL string. There are 2 solutions:

- Put your site behind a reverse proxy like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) + decrypt SSL (HAProxy 1.5 can do that, or you can put stunnel/nginx before it to decrypt SSL)
- Block it on whatever target server you are using

Answer (score 2):

Just use the permission system of your web server, e.g. via `.htaccess` files in case of Apache.